# Table Not Generated Using CodeFirst

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, ef-code-first

I am trying to generate database using CodeFirst but a table is not being generated.
Class Model Relation: (-> means Inherited By)
EntityBase -> Company -> Customer

FluentAPI Config:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .HasKey(k => k.CustomerReference)
            .HasRequired(r => r.Company)
            .WithMany(m => m.Customers)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.FKCompanyReference);

modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .HasKey(c => c.CompanyReference);
```

I have only Company and Customer in my context. CodeFirst generates Company table but not Customer table.
Is it because of the inheritance in my model because I tried with 'flat' domain class model it works fine.
Please, any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is because of inheritance. By default **TPH** (table per hierarchy) inheritance is used. So, you have single *Company* table, which includes all properties of classes in hierarchy. Add `ToTable` mapping to implement **TPT** (table per type) inheritance.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .ToTable("Customer");
```

Comment: AFAIK, **ToTable()** maps the entity to the table. MSDN also says so. Is it also used to enforce **TPH** to **TPT** ?

Comment: @Md.lbrahim yes. Because particular member of inheritance hierarchy will be mapped to own table. Of course it does not make separate tables for other entities from hierarchy.